# Geometry algorithm - Convex hull of line segments

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Given a set of pariwise disjoint line segments $S=s_1 , s_2 , ...., s_n $, the set of all the endpoints $C=x_1,y_1,.....x_n,y_n$ and the convex hull of $C$ , $CH(C)$

Prove that for any point $q$ external to CH(C) exists always a line segment of S that can be entirely seen from $q$ and give an algorithm (something better then brute force) to compute it.

Proof:
The first tought was that every other endpoint of $C$ that is not part of $CH(C)$ is inside the convex hull. but so not much ideas more

Comment: Are we talking 2d here? What means "can be seen from $q$"? What might potentially prevent a line segment from being seen? Another line segment or the convex hull? Because in the latter case your statement is probably false.

Comment: My first instinct would be to start by doing a projective transformation the puts $q$ at infinity in the positive $y$ direction, which is always possible because $q$ is outside the convex hull. This reduces the problem to having a number of non-intersecting affine functions on intervals, and needing to prove that one of them dominate the others.

Comment: Yesbitz, if you write "@Mario" instead of "To mario:", the site will ping him with your comment in his inbox.

Comment: @Mario: yes we are in 2d and "can be seen from q" means that there is other member of S inside the area defined by the triangle having as vertices the point q and the endpoints of the segment

Comment: @HenningMakholm: do you mean y direction in the case q is upon everything ? and what you mean with "dominate" the others ?